# Convert a Tree like List of Strings to xml

Tags: java, xml, data-structures, tree, logic

I need to convert these type of strings which are stored in an ArrayList :

```
Alpha.Beta.Com.
Alpa.Xeta.Hash.
Alpha.Eta.Dot.
Alpha.Eta.Comma.
Alpha.Eta.Dollar.
Alpha.Xeta.Tilde
Alpha.Beta.Com.Xeta.
```

here Alpha.Beta.Com. will have Xeta as child ,but Xeta must not have Hash and Tilde as children in this object.
Only,Alpha.Xeta object will have Hash and Tilde as children

these strings are like tree like structure(n levels) which means ,Alpha has Beta,Xeta & Eta as Child.
Furthermore,Beta has Com,
Xeta has Hash & Tilde,
Eta has Comma,Dollar & Dot as child.

We need to identify each parent and child using java program and then build it to XML.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Hi Guido,Thanks for the reply,can you please answer or send reference links for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class StringsToXmlConverter {

    private static final String SEPARTOR = "\\.";

    List<String> list;

    Map<String, XmlElement> elements = new HashMap<String,XmlElement>();

    public StringsToXmlConverter(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public String getXml() {
        for (String xmlPaths: list) {
            String[] splitedElements = xmlPaths.split(SEPARTOR);
            XmlElement parent = null;
            for (String elem : splitedElements) {
                XmlElement currentElem = null;
                if (elements.containsKey(elem)) {
                    currentElem = elements.get(elem);
                    if (parent != null) {
                        addChild(parent, currentElem);
                    } 
                } else {
                    currentElem = createNewElement(parent, elem);
                    elements.put(elem, currentElem);
                }
                parent = currentElem;
            }
        }

        return buildXml().toString();
    }

    private void addChild(XmlElement parent, XmlElement currentElem) {
        currentElem.parent = parent;
        parent.childs.add(currentElem);
    }

    private XmlElement createNewElement(XmlElement parent, String name) {
        XmlElement currentElem;
        currentElem = new XmlElement();
        currentElem.name = name;
        if (parent != null) {
            addChild(parent, currentElem);
        }
        return currentElem;
    }

    private StringBuilder buildXml() {
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
        for(XmlElement elem : elements.values()) {
            if (elem.parent == null) {
                xml.append(elem.toXml());
            }
        }
        return xml;
    }

    private class XmlElement {
        String name;
        Set<XmlElement> childs = new HashSet<XmlElement>();
        XmlElement parent = null;
        boolean isPrinted = false;

        private Set<XmlElement> getNoPrintedChilds() {
           Set<XmlElement> notPrintedChilds = new HashSet<XmlElement>();
           Iterator<XmlElement> iterator = childs.iterator();
           while(iterator.hasNext()) {
               XmlElement node = iterator.next();
               if (!node.isPrinted) {
                   notPrintedChilds.add(node);
               }
           }
           return notPrintedChilds;
        }

        public String toXml() {
           StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
           if (!isPrinted) {
               xml.append("<" + name); 
               if (getNoPrintedChilds().isEmpty()) {
                xml.append("/>");
               } else {
                   xml.append(">");
                   for (XmlElement elem : getNoPrintedChilds()) {
                       xml.append(elem.toXml());
                   }
                   xml.append("</" + name + ">");
               }
           }
           isPrinted = true;
           return xml.toString();
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + getOuterType().hashCode();
            result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            XmlElement other = (XmlElement) obj;
            if (!getOuterType().equals(other.getOuterType()))
                return false;
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        private StringsToXmlConverter getOuterType() {
            return StringsToXmlConverter.this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list= Arrays.asList("Alpha.Beta.Com", 
                                         "Alpha.Xeta.Hash", 
                                         "Alpha.Eta.Dot",
                                         "Alpha.Eta.Comma",
                                         "Alpha.Eta.Dollar",
                                         "Alpha.Xeta.Tilde");
        StringsToXmlConverter converter = new StringsToXmlConverter(list);
        System.out.println(converter.getXml());
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there any limit to it,i am getting stackoverflow error ,in lines 79 and 80 ,they are :79) for (XmlElement elem :childs) {
                     80)  xml.append(elem.toXml());

Comment: What exception do you get? Are you using the same test data or another?

Comment: Corrected that ,actually in my delimited string ,some of the dot separated characters were same ,which were resulting into that exception.

Comment: Alpha.Eta.Dollar.Xeta. is returning Tilde and Hash as child of  Alpha.Eta.Dollar.Xeta.,please help in this regard.

Comment: Please see the updated qquestion.

Comment: Here certain strings are causing the same key to be generated.Please help.

Comment: Do you want to get this result: <Alpha>
 <Eta>
  <Dollar />
  <Dot />
  <Comma />
 </Eta>
 <Xeta>
  <Tilde />
  <Hash />
 </Xeta>
 <Beta>
  <Com>
   <Xeta />
  </Com>
 </Beta>
</Alpha>

Comment: I changed program to print node just once.

Comment: No actually,i needed : <Alpha><Eta><Dollar/><Comma/><Dot/></Eta><Xeta><Hash/><Tilde/></Xeta><Beta><Com><Xeta/></Com></Beta></Alpha>

for "Alpha.Beta.Com", 
                                         "Alpha.Xeta.Hash", 
                                         "Alpha.Eta.Dot",
                                         "Alpha.Eta.Comma",
                                         "Alpha.Eta.Dollar",
                                         "Alpha.Xeta.Tilde",
                                         "Alpha.Beta.Com.Xeta"

Comment: in <Com> tag we must not have Xeta's children,because of only string "Alpha.Beta.Com.Xeta" is limited till Xeta,so here we don't need to have Xeta's children.

Comment: check now. I modified code.

Comment: I think there's misunderstanding ,Lets take an example :
"Alpha.Beta.Com", 
"Alpha.Xeta.Hash", 
"Alpha.Eta.Dot",
"Alpha.Eta.Comma",
"Alpha.Eta.Dollar",
"Alpha.Xeta.Tilde.Eta"

The output would be 
<Alpha><Eta><Dollar/><Comma/><Dot/></Eta><Beta><Com/></Beta><Xeta><Hash/><Tilde><Eta/></Tilde></Xeta></Alpha>

Tilde would have only Eta which is in string but would not have Eta's child listed.

Thanks in advance.Please help.

Comment: For your example above use the program, which i modified the first time: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26143716/2 . The program prints name of children (without their children) if the node was printed before. Remember to change the input list in main function on list from your last comment. You will see the same xml as you generated - I tested it.